# Sum of elements, differences between code

Tags: javascript, sum

I have two pieces of code both calculating the sum of the elements of an array:

```
var sum = array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
    return previousValue + currentValue;
}, 0);
```

or

```
var sum = 0;
array.forEach(function(e) {
    sum += e;
});
```

Are there any differences between them beside different implementations? When is it better to use which one?

Comment: Both are valid and choosing one or the other is a matter of preference. I personally like `reduce` better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides your personal style preference, there could be also difference in actual performance. Those two look to perform similarly however.

If you're doing this operation a lot (or for large arrays) consider using the third way:

```
var sum = 0;
for (l = array.length; l--; ) { sum += array[l]; }
```

This will be way faster. Check [this performance test](http://jsperf.com/summing-array) for actual results.

**Note:** you will gain some speed if you cache array length. So instead of doing this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {...}
```

Do this:

```
var l = array.length;
for (; l--; ) { ... }
```

or this:

```
for (l = array.length; l--;) { ... }
```

Comment: Or `while(l--){ ... }`

Answer (score 2):

First one is slightly heavier than the second one.
The fastest way is to avoid calling functions for each step and use loops like `for`.

```
var sum = 0;
for(var i=0, len=array.length; i<len; i++){
    sum += array[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

as using both of these function involves executing the callback function for each element that would incur the function calling overhead (so both re not efficent), using loop will give better performance.